# Определение пользователя по Cookie

Tags: безопасность

По какому принципу сервер (контроллер) принимает куки без капчи?
MAC/Метаданные?
Если вставить куки файлы в другой браузер, будет ли проход аутентификации без капчи?

Comment: Как вы реализуете, по тому принципу и будет

Comment: Куки для сервера - это всего лишь заголовок в запросе.

Comment: вы просто должны исключить перехват cookie, например используя https что бы их в сети не перехватили. А если злоумышленник получит доступ к компу то вы все равно ничего не сделаете, потому что он может воспользоваться тем же самым браузером

Comment: Может будет, может нет...